# Table with an itemized list in second column

Tags: tables

A colleague of mine asked me for help creating the following picture using tex code.

[image: table with lists in second column]
<sub>(source: [redwoods.edu](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/questions/MichelleTable.png))</sub>

Can someone share a bit of code, maybe for the first two rows?

=======================================================================================

Thanks to suggestions below and the following link:

[mori table article](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf)

I was able to do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!20}
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{8cm}|}
\hline
Strengths & 
- Increase the number of tourists\newline
- Easy to start a business\newline
- Favorable tax System\\
\hline
Weakness & 
- Limited Resources\newline
- High start-up costs\\
\hline
Opportunities & 
- target markets by country of origin or interests\\
\hline
Threats & 
- High level of competition\newline
- Difficulty in attracting and maintaining customers\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result was this image. My colleague is grateful.

[image]

Comment: It requires a tabular with a parbox for the 2nd column, most probably

Comment: Sometihng like `\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!70}`, should do the job regarding coloration. Load tabularx and xcolor with the option table.

Answer (score 1):

More or less like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{6cm}|}
\hline
Strenghts & \begin{itemize}
\item{Increase the number of tourists}
\item{Easy to start a business}
\item{Favorable tax System}
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
Weakness & \begin{itemize}
\item{Limited Resources}
\item{High start-up costs}
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
Opportunities & \begin{itemize}
\item{target markets by country of origin or interests}
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
Threats & \begin{itemize}
\item{High level of competition}
\item{Difficulty in attractingand maintaining customers}
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please add a few more lines of code to convert your code snippet into a full MWE -- a LaTeX "program" that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and is compilable.

Comment: This needs some more code and a screenshot of its output